# Probability of intersection of n dependent events

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve the following question:

A cube is thrown 20 times.
Define: $A_i$ - the number i appeared exactly $i$ times.

Find $P(A_2\cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5 \cap A_6)$

I know the following formula:

$P(A_2\cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5 \cap A_6) = P(A_2)P(A_3 |A_2)P(A_4|A_2\cap A_3)... P(A_6|A_2 \cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5)$

The question is, which of the following (or none of which) is true:

1) $P(A_4|A_2 \cap A_3) = {15\choose4}(1/6)^{4}(5/6)^{11}$

2) $P(A_4|A_2 \cap A_3) = {15\choose4}(1/6)^{4}(3/6)^{11}$

If I choose the second option, the answer is dependent on the order I choose for calculating the different probs, hence I assume it's the wrong way. Still, the first method seems not right to me because it doesn't promoise that $A_2 \cap A_3$ occur.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are wrong. Let us find the desired probability by definition of conditional probability: 
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
P(A_4|A_2 \cap A_3) = \frac{P(A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4)}{P(A_2\cap A_3)}$$
First find $P(A_2\cap A_3)$. By ${20\choose2}$  ways, we can choose two trials in which $2$ appears. Then by ${18\choose3}$  ways, we can choose three trials in which $3$ appears. Other $15$ trials can show any number except of $2$ and $3$. Then
$$\tag{2}\label{2}
P(A_2\cap A_3)={20\choose2}{18\choose3}(1/6)^{2}(1/6)^{3}(4/6)^{15}
$$
Other way we can find this probability using multinomial distribution:
$$
P(A_2\cap A_3)=\frac{20!}{2!\,3!\,15!}(1/6)^{2}(1/6)^{3}(4/6)^{15}
$$
but the previous formula seems to be better for our further goal. Similar way we can find the probability of 
$$\tag{3}\label{3}
P(A_2\cap A_3\cap A_4)={20\choose2}{18\choose3}{15\choose4}(1/6)^{2}(1/6)^{3}(1/6)^{4}(3/6)^{11}.
$$
Substitute the numerator (\ref{3}) and denominator (\ref{2}) into fraction (\ref{1}):
$$
P(A_4|A_2 \cap A_3) = \frac{{20\choose2}{18\choose3}{15\choose4}(1/6)^{2}(1/6)^{3}(1/6)^{4}(3/6)^{11}}{{20\choose2}{18\choose3}(1/6)^{2}(1/6)^{3}(4/6)^{15}}=\frac{{15\choose4}(1/6)^{4}(3/6)^{11}}{(4/6)^{15}}={15\choose4}(1/4)^{4}(3/4)^{11}.
$$
As you can see. this is exactly the probability of $4$ successes in $15$ undependent trial with success probability $1/4$. One can get either $4$ or $1,5,6$ on a cube in each trial, and need to get $4$ exactly $4$ times.

Please also note that the original probability can be found explicitely without any conditioning but using multinomial distribution:
$$
P(A_2\cap A_3 \cap A_4 \cap A_5 \cap A_6) = \frac{20!}{2!\,3!\,4!\,5!\,6!}(1/6)^{20}.
$$